# What does this GetLine function do?

Tags: c

```
void GetLine(FILE *fp)
{   
    char one_char;
    one_char = fgetc(fp);

    do
    {
        one_char = fgetc(fp);
    } while (!feof(fp) && one_char != 10);

}
```

Can someone explain in detail what this code does?

```
FILE *fp
...

fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &inull, &nbmat);
GetLine(fp);

for (i = 0; i < nbmat; i++)
{
    fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &tcode, &n);
...
```

the file like this:

```
1 12 Description of $CODE
20012 1 Compressibility of fluid 0
0.0
...
```

I know steps：

1. first fscanf read file number 1 12 to inull and nbmat;
2. GetLine jump to next line ???
3. for loop : i=0-->11;
4. second fscanf read file number 20012 1 to tcode and n ??
   ...

I want to know what `GetLine` does.

Comment: It reads a line and discards it. 10 being the confused would-be programmer's way of writing `'\n'`.

Comment: The author of `GetLine` probably intended that it skip until the end of the line, but if the stream is already at the end of  a line it will skip the next line.  If there is a read error, it enters an infinite loop.  It is poorly written and should not be emulated or used until fixed.

Comment: so the file must written in a format

Answer (score 3):

> i want to know GetLine does;

Assuming everything goes correctly, it skips from the current position to the beginning of the next line by reading forward, character-by-character, until it comes to ascii value 10, [aka. "linefeed"](https://www.ascii-code.com/).

As William Pursell commented, it is not very robust:

> If the first character read is a newline, it will discard it and the next. If there is a read error, it may loop indefinitely. From the sample input, it seems that it is intended to consume comments in the input. –

The line it reads into the program is discarded, rather than saved anywhere.

Comment: If the first character read is a newline, it will discard it *and* the next.  If there is a read error, it may loop indefinitely.   From the sample input, it seems that it is intended to consume comments in the input.

Comment: @WilliamPursell yes, good eye. I'll edit for clarity.

Comment: many thanks；
I was confused about 10 before.  and the streamLine is forward.